# Multithread Each process in multithread many times

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a program that consists of 4 processes, all of them needs to be run one after another.

Sketch is like this:

1st process - in multithread 
 - finished his work provided data input

2nd process - in multithread
 - finished his work provided some data

3rd process - in multithread
 - finished his work provided some data

4th process - in multithread
 - finished his work provided data output

Note in order for one process to start the one before him needs to be finished!

In code sketch looks like this:

```
public class MainClass{

public static void main(){
    addThreadPool();
}

public static void addThreadPool(){

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor eventPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);

eventPool.sheduleAtFixedRate(new FirstProcess(),0,5, TimeUnits.SECONDS);
eventPool.sheduleAtFixedRate(new SecondProcess(),5,10, TimeUnits.SECONDS);
eventPool.sheduleAtFixedRate(new ThirdProcess(),15,20, TimeUnits.SECONDS);
eventPool.sheduleAtFixedRate(new ForthProcess(),20,25, TimeUnits.SECONDS);


try{
   Thread.sleep(20000);
}
catch(InterruptedException e){
System.err.println(e.getMessaage());
}
}


static class FirstProcess implements Runnable {
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void run(){
lock.lock();

System.out.println("FirstProcess started/finished");    

lock.unlock();
}

}



static class SecondProcess implements Runnable {
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void run(){
lock.lock();

System.out.println("SecondProcess started/finished");    

lock.unlock();
}

}

static class ThirdProcess implements Runnable {
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void run(){
lock.lock();

System.out.println("ThirdProcess started/finished");    

lock.unlock();
}

}

static class ForthProcess implements Runnable {
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void run(){
lock.lock();

System.out.println("ForthProcess started/finished");    

lock.unlock();
}

}
```

I hope someone has answer it's simple multithread question.

Please help by using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor!

Comment: Why do you have to have them as four separate runnables? Just bundle them together in one runnable and call that.

Comment: What is the point in using 4 different threads, if they have to run sequentially anyway? It seems you're missing the point of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the eventPool into the constructor for Second, Third, and FourthProcess. Have FirstProcess create and schedule SecondProcess, etc.

There's probably a better way to do it, and I wouldn't be satisfied with the answer, but it should work.